# VB.NET - Starting another windows application in the same solution?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two windows applications in the same solution, in different projects. How do I start one from the other? Is it a matter of supplying the expected build path .exe to somewhere, or is there an alternative?

Comment: do you want to start them both for debugging? or you just want to launch one from the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `Process.Start()`, passing the full path of the executable and you should be fine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx